# VB parameterization using string literals instead of assigning Params

Tags: sql, vb.net, parameters, parameterization

I am attempting to parameterize my query, but I can see with the message box, the actual query is just using string literals @st & @sn instead of the values passed in. I really can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```vb
Protected Function UpdateDeviceStatus(serial_Num As String, Site As String, Status As String) As Boolean
    Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Status:" + Status + "  SN:" + serial_Num + "  Site: " + Site)
    Using db = DBConnect()
        db.CommandText = $"
        UPDATE myTable SET Status =  @st WHERE serial_number = @sn "


        db.AddParameter("@st", Status)
        db.AddParameter("@sn", serial_Num)
        Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(db.CommandText)
        db.Execute()
        Return True
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with vb.net. If this was c# I would say to change ".AddParameter" to ".AddParameterWithValue".

Comment: @GeorgeMastros First, the `db` object looks to be a custom wrapper or from something like Dapper, so `AddParameterWithValue()` probably does not exist. Second, even if it did, there are reasons to avoid it in favor of other strongly-typed mechanisms for setting the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

This is how it's supposed to work.

The *whole point* of query parameters is the parameter values are **NEVER**, at any time, substituted directly into the SQL command. Instead, parameter values are sent to the database server in a completely separate data block from the command text. In this way, any possibility of injection is prevented.

If you had an idea parametrized queries were about correctly *escaping* the the inputs for inclusion in the query, this idea was incorrect. Parameterized queries do not escape the provided data! Rather, they **quarantine** it.

Therefore you will never be able to show the completed SQL command in a MessageBox, and that's a good thing. It will still execute with the intended values when you actually run it.

Answer (score -1):

See the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=netframework-4.8.1#examples)

What you are looking for is **Command.Parameters.AddWithValue**